# Jquery Flot not update x-Axis realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, flot

I had a problem with jquery flot.

I want to update realtime `x-axis` every 5 seconds. But it only update `x-axis` a little time, and after that, it didn't update label `x-axis`.

Can anybody explain for me, why it din't update ? Thank you very much.

Here my link demo:
[This is my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/khanhpn/g2CTz/464/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only define your xaxis ticks once and never update them when the data changes. So they move out of your chart to the left.

Add the following code to your `GetDataHour()` function to add new ticks every hour when you add new data:

```
if (now_hour - options_hour.xaxis.ticks[options_hour.xaxis.ticks.length - 1] === 3600000) {
  options_hour.xaxis.ticks.push(now_hour);
}
```

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2CTz/467/) for the full code.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got your idea.